# Using inotify in a script to monitor a directory

Tags: linux, bash, echo, monitoring, inotifywait

I have written a bash script to monitor a particular directory "/root/secondfolder/" the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh

while inotifywait -mr -e close_write "/root/secondfolder/"
do
    echo "close_write"
done
```

When I create a file called "fourth.txt" in "/root/secondfolder/" and write stuff to it, save and close it, it outputs the following but it does not echo "close_write":

```
/root/secondfolder/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE fourth.txt
```

can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out all I had to do was pipe the command into a while loop:

```
!/bin/sh

inotifywait -mqr -e close_write "/root/secondfolder/" | while read line
do
echo "close_write"
done
```

Comment: ... And you could *invert the fork* see [my answer there.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36870432/1765658)

Answer (score 6):

You are not far away from solution. If you want to use `inotifywait` in your `while` statement you should not use `-m` option. With this option `inotifywait` never end because it's the `monitor` option. So you never go into the `while`.

This should work :

```
#!/bin/sh

while inotifywait -r -e close_write "/root/secondfolder/"
do
    echo "close_write"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I found another solution that allows me to monitor the directory indefinitely and get the output.

Comment: This is suboptimal because there may be multiple close_writes before the next inotifywait process starts. It's better to use inotifywait's --monitor mode if you care about processing every single message.