# How to monitor newly created file in a directory with bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a log directory that consists of bunch of log files, one log file is created once an system event has happened. I want to write an oneline bash script that always monitors the file list and display the content of the newly created file on the terminal. Here is what it looks like:

Currently, all I have is to display the content of the whole directory:

```
for f in *; do cat $f; done
```

It lacks the monitoring feature that I wanted. One limitation of my system is that I **do not have** `watch` command. I also don't have any package manager to install fancy tools. Raw BSD is all I have. I do have `tail`, I was thinking of something like `tail -F $(ls)` but this tails each file instead of the file list.

In summary, I want to modify my script such that I can monitor the content of all newly created files.

Comment: I don't understand your limitations! Why did you not have `watch`? What's your system, version?

Answer (score 4):

1. First approach - use a hidden file in you dir (in my example it has a name `.watch`). Then you one-liner might look like:

   ```
   for f in $(find . -type f -newer .watch); do cat $f; done; touch .watch
   ```
2. Second approach - use inotify-tools: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273556/when-a-particular-file-arrives-then-execute-a-procedure-using-shell-script/273563#273563

Comment: I like this one (first approach).

Comment: @Simon  You'd better: `touch .newmark;find -newer .watch ... ; mv .newmark .watch` for ensuring not missing files that will arrive between `find` and `touch`!!

Comment: don't you need to put `touch .watch` in the for loop to enable continuous rolling? I think your script would only run once and leave a .watch file with latest modification date in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can cram it into a one-liner if you want, but I'd recommend just running the script in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ ! -d "$1" ] && {
    printf "error: argument is not a valid directory to monitory.\n"
    exit 1
}

while :; fname="$1/$(inotifywait -q -e modify -e create --format '%f' "$1")"; do
    cat "$fname"
done
```

Which will watch the directory given as the first argument, and `cat` any new or changed file in that directory. Example:

```
$ bash watchdir.sh my_logdir &
```

Which will then `cat` new or changed files in `my_logdir`.

Comment: *Monitor mode loop* is better dans *forever loop* and *one shot inotifywait*, because of even that could occur when `inotifywait` not running. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36870432/1765658)

Comment: Yes, I played with that, I just didn't want to leave `read` blocking. I guess it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `inotifywait` in *monitor* mode

First this little demo:

1. Open one terminal and run this:

   ```
   ext=(php css other)
   while :;do
       subname=''
       ((RANDOM%10))||printf -v subname -- "-%04x" $RANDOM
       date >/tmp/test$subname.${ext[RANDOM%3]}
       sleep 1
     done
   ```

   This will create randomly files named `/tmp/test.php`, `/tmp/test.css` and `/tmp/test.other`, but randomly (approx 1 time / 10), the name will be `/tmp/test-XXXX.[css|php|other]` where XXXX is an hexadecimal random number.
2. Open another terminal and run this:

   ```
   waitPaths=(/{home,tmp})
   while read file ;do
       if [ "$file" ] &&
        ( [ -z "${file##*.php}" ] || [ -z  "${file##*.css}" ] ) ;then
           (($(stat -c %Y-%X $file)))||echo -n new
           echo file: $file, content:
           cat $file
       fi
     done < <(
       inotifywait -qme close_write --format %w%f ${waitPaths[*]}
   )
   ```

   This may produce something like:

   ```
   file: /tmp/test.css, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:19 CEST 2016
   file: /tmp/test.php, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:21 CEST 2016
   file: /tmp/test.php, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:23 CEST 2016
   file: /tmp/test.css, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:25 CEST 2016
   file: /tmp/test.php, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:27 CEST 2016
   newfile: /tmp/test-420b.php, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:28 CEST 2016
   file: /tmp/test.php, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:29 CEST 2016
   file: /tmp/test.php, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:30 CEST 2016
   file: /tmp/test.php, content:
   Tue Apr 26 18:53:31 CEST 2016
   ```

#### Some explanation:

- `waitPaths=(/{home,tmp})` could be written `waitPaths=(/home /tmp)` or for only one directory: `waitPaths=/var/log`
- `if` condition search for filenames matching `*.php` or `*.css`
- `(($(stat -c %Y-%X $file)))||echo -n new` will compare *creation* and *modification* time.
- `inotifywait`

  - `-q` to stay `quiet` (don't print more then required)
  - `-m` for *monitor* mode: Command don't termine, but print each matching event.
  - `-e close_write` react only to specified kind of event.
  - `-f %w%f`  Output format: *`path/file`*

#### Another way:

There is a more sophisticated sample:

- Listenning for two kind of events (CLOSE_WRITE | CREATE)
- Using a list of new files flags for knowing which files are new when CLOSE_WRITE event occur.

In second console, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or in new terminal, tris this:

```
waitPaths=(/{home,tmp})
declare -A newFiles
while read path event file; do
    if [ "$file" ] && ( [ -z "${file##*.php}" ] || [ -z "${file##*.css}" ] ); then
        if [ "$event" ] && [ -z "${event//*CREATE*}" ]; then
            newFiles[$file]=1
        else
            if [ "${newFiles[$file]}" ]; then
                unset newFiles[$file]
                echo NewFile: $file, content:
                sed 's/^/>+ /' $file
            else
                echo file: $file, content:
                sed 's/^/>  /' $path/$file
            fi
        fi
    fi
done < <(inotifywait -qme close_write -e create ${waitPaths[*]})
```

May produce something like:

```
file: test.css, content:
>  Tue Apr 26 22:16:02 CEST 2016
file: test.php, content:
>  Tue Apr 26 22:16:03 CEST 2016
NewFile: test-349b.css, content:
>+ Tue Apr 26 22:16:05 CEST 2016
file: test.css, content:
>  Tue Apr 26 22:16:08 CEST 2016
file: test.css, content:
>  Tue Apr 26 22:16:10 CEST 2016
file: test.css, content:
>  Tue Apr 26 22:16:13 CEST 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

### Watching for new files AND new lines in old files, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

There is another solution by using some *bashisms* like *associative arrays*:

Sample:

```
wpath=/var/log
while : ;do
    while read -a crtfile ;do
        if [ "${crtfile:0:1}" = "-" ] &&
          [ "${crtfile[8]##*.}" != "gz" ] &&
          [ "${files[${crtfile[8]}]:-0}" -lt ${crtfile[4]} ] ;then
            printf "\e[47m## %-14s :- %(%a %d %b %y %T)T ##\e[0m\n" ${crtfile[8]} -1
            tail -c +$[1+${files[${crtfile[8]}]:-0}] $wpath/${crtfile[8]}
            files[${crtfile[8]}]=${crtfile[4]}
        fi
    done < <( /bin/ls -l $wpath )
    sleep 1
done
```

This will dump each files (with filename not ending by `.gz`) in `/var/log`, and watch for modification or new files, then dump new lines.

#### Demo:

1. In a first terminal console, hit:

   ```bash
   ext=(php css other)
   ( while :; do
       subname=''
       ((RANDOM%10)) || printf -v subname -- "-%04x" $RANDOM
       name=test$subname.${ext[RANDOM%3]}
       printf "%-16s" $name
       { 
           date +"%a %d %b %y %T" | tee /dev/fd/5
           fortune /usr/share/games/fortunes/bofh-excuses
       } >> /tmp/$name
       sleep 1
   done ) 5>&1
   ```

   You need to have `fortune` installed with *BOFH excuses* librarie.

   If you really not have `fortune`, you could use this instead:

   ```bash
   LANG=C ext=(php css other)
   ( while :; do
       subname=''
       ((RANDOM%10)) || printf -v subname -- "-%04x" $RANDOM
       name=test$subname.${ext[RANDOM%3]}
       printf "%-16s" $name
       { 
           date +"%a %d %b %y %T" | tee /dev/fd/5
           for ((1; RANDOM%5; 1))
           do
               printf -v str %$[RANDOM&12]s
               str=${str// /blah, }
               echo ${str%, }.
           done
       } >> /tmp/$name
       sleep 1
   done ) 5>&1
   ```

   This may output something like:

   ```
   test.css        Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:02
   test.php        Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:03
   test.other      Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:04
   test.css        Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:05
   test.css        Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:06
   test.other      Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:07
   test.php        Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:08
   test.css        Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:09
   test.other      Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:10
   test.other      Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:11
   test.php        Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:12
   test.other      Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:13
   ```
2. In a second terminal console, hit:

   ```bash
   declare -A files
   wpath=/tmp
   while :; do
       while read -a crtfile; do
           if [ "${crtfile:0:1}" = "-" ] && [ "${crtfile[8]:0:4}" = "test" ] &&
            ( [ "${crtfile[8]##*.}" = "css" ] || [ "${crtfile[8]##*.}" = "php" ] ) &&
            [ "${files[${crtfile[8]}]:-0}" -lt ${crtfile[4]} ]; then
               printf "\e[47m## %-14s :- %(%a %d %b %y %T)T ##\e[0m\n" ${crtfile[8]} -1
               tail -c +$[1+${files[${crtfile[8]}]:-0}] $wpath/${crtfile[8]}
               files[${crtfile[8]}]=${crtfile[4]}
           fi
       done < <(/bin/ls -l $wpath)
       sleep 1
   done
   ```

This will each seconds

1. for all entries in watched directory

   1. search for *files* (first caracter is `-`),
   2. search for filenames begining by `test`,
   3. search for filenames ending by `css` or `php`,
   4. compare *already printed sizes* with new file size,
   5. if new size greater,

      - print out new bytes by using `tail -c` and
      - store new *already printed size*
   6. sleep 1 seconds

   this may output something like:

   ```
   ## test.css       :- Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:09 ##
   Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:02
   BOFH excuse #216:

   What office are you in? Oh, that one.  Did you know that your building was built over the universities first nuclear research site? And wow, aren't you the lucky one, your office is right over where the core is buried!
   Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:05
   BOFH excuse #145:

   Flat tire on station wagon with tapes.  ("Never underestimate the bandwidth of a station wagon full of tapes hurling down the highway" Andrew S. Tannenbaum) 
   Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:06
   BOFH excuse #301:

   appears to be a Slow/Narrow SCSI-0 Interface problem
   ## test.php       :- Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:09 ##
   Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:03
   BOFH excuse #36:

   dynamic software linking table corrupted
   Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:08
   BOFH excuse #367:

   Webmasters kidnapped by evil cult.
   ## test.css       :- Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:10 ##
   Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:09
   BOFH excuse #25:

   Decreasing electron flux
   ## test.php       :- Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:13 ##
   Thu 28 Apr 16 12:00:12
   BOFH excuse #3:

   electromagnetic radiation from satellite debris
   ```

   Nota: If some file are modified more than one time between two checks, all modification will be printed on next check.

Comment: @return0: This solution is nice because it use only [tag:bash],  `ls` and `tail` (and `sleep`, but you could use `read -t` instead). This print all, but only *new lines* in all (even new) files! Did you try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Although not really nice, the following gives (and repeats) the last 50 lines of the newest file in the current directory:

```
while true; do tail -n 50 $(ls -Art | tail -n 1); sleep 5; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh every minute using a cronjob:

```
$crontabe -e


 * * * * * /home/script.sh
```

if you need to refresh in less than a minute you can use the command "sleep" inside your script.